# Уровни и скорость в тэтрисе(класический)

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр

Написал аналог тэтриса, но не смог найти данные о скорости и уровнях в тэтрисе. В связи с чем изменяется уровень и как изменяется при этом скорость (время дефолтного опускания фигурки на 1 клетку) в классическом тэтрисе?

Comment: Уменьшить таймер или delay разве нет?

Comment: @Duoxx вы вообще о чем?

Comment: Ну у вас же с каким-то интервалом кирпичик опускается

Comment: А вы имеете ввиду время опускания в клас. тетрисе тогда я думаю стоит поиграть и посмотреть.

Comment: @Duoxx вы мне предлагаете поиграть до 18 уровня и с секундомером замерять время за которое кирпичик опускается? А давайте я вам дам свой совет: предлагаю сначала думать, прежде чем давать подобные советы.

Comment: Все-же я не вижу проблемы задать произвольное значение, по крайнер мере я так тетрис делал. Простите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для скорости есть такая формула и таблица

Time = (0.8-((Level-1)*0.007))<sup>(Level-1)</sup>

```
Level   Speed    (unit: G)
1   0.01667
2   0.021017
3   0.026977
4   0.035256
5   0.04693
6   0.06361
7   0.0879
8   0.1236
9   0.1775
10  0.2598
11  0.388
12  0.59
13  0.92
14  1.46
15  2.36
```

Условием изменения уровней [тут](http://tetris.wikia.com/wiki/Tetris_Guideline) указано 8 собранных линий, хотя мне кажется, что это количество могло зависеть от текущего уровня

Comment: что-то я не пойму эту формулу: в конце это возведение в степень? В таком случае получается, что время ростем вместе с уровнем?

Comment: Величина в скобках меньше единицы, поэтому с уровнем результат (время) уменьшается. А далее таблица для ускорения свободного падения (G) - применяется ли это ускорение для нарастания скорости от начальной, если применяется, то всегда или опционально, или оно вообще для быстрого дропа, я не знаю